# Shortest way to iterate over 3 pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the shortest way to do the following?

```
i = 0
for Year, Month, Day in zip(test_data['Year'], test_data['Month'], test_data['Day']):
    ans = dt.date(Year, Month, Day)
    test_data.loc[i,'Day1'] = ans.strftime("%A")
    i += 1
```

Comment: How do you define shortest? In execution time?

Comment: Hi David, Yes in terms of execution time. Sorry for not specifying it in the question.
Marius' comment precisely answered the problem. Thanks Marius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `apply` over the rows, which avoids having to `zip` and keep track of which row you're up to:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [2015, 2016], 'Month': [12, 1], 'Day': [28, 3]})

df
Out[3]: 
   Day  Month  Year
0   28     12  2015
1    3      1  2016

df['Day1'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: dt.date(row['Year'], row['Month'], row['Day']).strftime('%A'),
    axis='columns')
```

Output:

```
df
Out[11]: 
   Day  Month  Year    Day1
0   28     12  2015  Monday
1    3      1  2016  Sunday
```